# What combination of generic parameter constraints will make the C# compiler generate rows for the GenericParamConstraint metadata table?

Tags: .net, clr, metadata, cil

According to the Partition II metadata specification for the GenericParamConstraint table for the CLR,

> The GenericParamConstraint table
>   records the constraints for each
>   generic parameter. Each generic
>   parameter can be constrained to derive
>   from zero or one class. Each generic
>   parameter can be constrained to
>   implement zero or more interfaces.

The problem is that I can't seem to find the right C# code snippet to have the C# compiler generate a single row in the GenericParamConstraint table. I have tried using

```
    public interface IFoo
    {
    }

    public interface IBaz
    {
    }

    public interface IBar
    {
    }
    public class Foo
    {

    }
    public class SampleClassWithGenericParamConstraint<T>
        where T : IFoo, IBaz, new()
    {
        public void DoSomething<U>(U arg1)
            where U : struct
        {
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
```

..but the problem is that the C# compiler only generates rows for the GenericParam table instead of adding rows for the GenericParamConstraint table. So here's my question--is there any code sample written in C# that would force the C# compiler to add a metadata row to the GenericParamConstraint table so that I could use the sample binary? And if this is some sort of limitation on the C# compiler's part, is there an equivalent ILASM snippet that would do the job instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be confused, the exact code you posted, compiled with csc, results in three rows in the GenericParamConstraint table.

[image]

In this context, the GenericParam `U` has a token of 2a000001, and is constrained on the System.ValueType TypeRef. `T` (2a00000a) is constrained on the IFoo and IBaz TypeDefs.